# How to enforce that a function should be called with a coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there a way to make it so that a function has to be called with a coroutine in an IO scope?

I guess I can do

```
suspend fun f() {}
```

But maybe there is an annotation for this?

What if I still want the function to be blocking? Because inside the function I am usually doing db calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a suspend function, it will certainly only be callable from coroutines.

As for requiring it to be called in an IO scope, you *could* just install the IO dispatcher yourself:

```
suspend fun f() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }
```

...or, if you *really* wanted to just reject any user who wasn't using the IO dispatcher, you could write `require(coroutineContext[CoroutineInterceptor] == Dispatchers.IO)`, but I'd certainly find that very strange as a user.

Comment: Where would that `require(coroutineContext[CoroutineInterceptor] == Dispatchers.IO)` go in the code?

Comment: @J_Strauton if you write the function as suggested above using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // your code }` this will be enough. The suspend function will run on a thread that comes from the IO dispatcher.

Comment: @J_Strauton it'd be the first line of your suspend function.